# How to intercept the first value of a generator and transparently yield from the rest

Tags: python, generator, yield-from

**Update:** I've started a [thread on python-ideas](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-ideas@python.org/thread/LRZQT7WXNX6JU2HUUOOTWI55B3Y6SUJ3/) to propose additional syntax or a stdlib function for this purpose (i.e. specifying the first value sent by `yield from`). So far 0 replies... :/

---

How do I intercept the first yielded value of a subgenerator but delegate the rest of the iteration to the latter using `yield from`?

For example, suppose we have an arbitrary bidirectional generator `subgen`, and we want to wrap this in another generator `gen`. The purpose of `gen` is to intercept the first yielded value of `subgen` and delegate the rest of the generation—**including sent values, thrown exceptions, .close(), etc.**—to the sub-generator.

The first thing that might come to mind could be this:

```py
def gen():
    g = subgen()

    first = next(g)
    # do something with first...
    yield "intercepted"

    # delegate the rest
    yield from g
```

But this is wrong, because when the caller `.send`s something back to the generator after getting the first value, it will end up as the value of the `yield "intercepted"` expression, which is ignored, and instead `g` will receive `None` as the first `.send` value, as part of the semantics of `yield from`.

So we might think to do this:

```py
def gen():
    g = subgen()

    first = next(g)
    # do something with first...
    received = yield "intercepted"
    g.send(received)

    # delegate the rest
    yield from g
```

But what we've done here is just moving the problem back by one step: as soon as we call `g.send(received)`, the generator resumes its execution and doesn't stop until it reaches the next yield statement, whose value becomes the return value of the `.send` call. So we'd also have to intercept that and re-send it. And then send *that*, and *that* again, and so on... So this won't do.

Basically, what I'm asking for is a `yield from` with a way to customize what the first value sent to the generator is:

```py
def gen():
    g = subgen()

    first = next(g)
    # do something with first...
    received = yield "intercepted"

    # delegate the rest
    yield from g start with received  # pseudocode; not valid Python
```

...but without having to re-implement all of the semantics of `yield from` myself. That is, the laborious and poorly maintainable solution would be:

```py
def adaptor(generator, init_send_value=None):
    send = init_send_value
    try:
        while True:
            send = yield generator.send(send)
    except StopIteration as e:
        return e.value
```

which is basically a bad re-implementation of `yield from` (it's missing handling of `throw`, `close`, etc.). Ideally I would like something more elegant and less redundant.

Comment: Is `x` None after you do: `x = yield 42`?

Comment: Not necessarily, `x` can be anything the caller sends in. Using Python 3.9

Comment: What Python are you using? Also how can be x anything the caller sends?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.9. For example, if using `subgen` directly: `g = subgen(); v = next(g); v = g.send(123)`. In the last statement, we sent 123 to `subgen`, and so `x` was 123. Then the generator reached the next yield statement and yielded `x + 2`, i.e. `125`; so `v` is now `125`. Keep in mind that the first `send` is just to initialise the generator (i.e. its value doesn't appear anywhere in the generator) and must always be `.send(None)`, or the equivalent `next()`.

Comment: See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send). "When send() is called to start the generator, it must be called with None as the argument, because there is no yield expression that could receive the value." But, after that, "the value argument becomes the result of the current yield expression."

Comment: I'm probably missing it, but why do you expect x to be 42 and not None after x = yield 42 ? Why not to redo your subgen using following pattern (separating lines with semicolon): x = 42; yield x; x += 2; yield x.

Comment: Adding to myself above. If you want to somehow alter sub-generator based on first value it produces, then use x = yield 42 only once and then yield x ongoing?

Comment: @MjH The `subgen` above is just a dummy example; in fact, since it's causing more confusion than anything, I'll remove it from the question. And I didn't say I expect x to be 42, quite the contrary: I don't have any expectations for its value, as it can be anything the caller sends with [`.send()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to implement this generator wrapper as a generator function using `yield from`, then your question basically boils down to whether it is possible to specify the first value sent to the "yielded from" generator. Which it is not.

If you look at the formal specification of the `yield from` expression in [PEP 380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#formal-semantics), you can see why. The specification contains a (surprisingly complex) piece of sample code that behaves the same as a `yield from` expression. The first few lines are:

```
_i = iter(EXPR)
try:
    _y = next(_i)
except StopIteration as _e:
    _r = _e.value
else:
    ...
```

You can see that the first thing that is done to the iterator is to call `next()` on it, which is basically equivalent to `.send(None)`. There is no way to skip that step and your generator will always receive another `None` whenever `yield from` is used.

The solution I've come up with is to implement the generator protocol using a class instead of a generator function:

```
class Intercept:
    def __init__(self, generator):
        self._generator = generator
        self._intercepted = False

    def __next__(self):
        return self.send(None)

    def send(self, value):
        yielded_value = self._generator.send(value)

        # Intercept the first value yielded by the wrapped generator and 
        # replace it with a different value.
        if not self._intercepted:
            self._intercepted = True

            print(f'Intercepted value: {yielded_value}')

            yielded_value = 'intercepted'

        return yielded_value

    def throw(self, type, *args):
        return self._generator.throw(type, *args)

    def close(self):
        self._generator.close()
```

`__next__()`, `send()`, `throw()`, `close()` are described in the [Python Reference Manual](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/expressions.html?highlight=throw#generator-iterator-methods).

The class wraps the generator passed to it when created will mimic its behavior. The only thing it changes is that the first value yielded by the generator is replaced by a different value before it is returned to the caller.

We can test the behavior with an example generator `f()` which yields two values and a function `main()` which sends values into the generator until the generator terminates:

```
def f():
    y = yield 'first'
    print(f'f(): {y}')

    y = yield 'second'
    print(f'f(): {y}')

def main():
    value_to_send = 0
    gen = f()

    try:
        x = gen.send(None)

        while True:
            print(f'main(): {x}')

            # Send incrementing integers to the generator.
            value_to_send += 1
            x = gen.send(value_to_send)
    except StopIteration:
        print('main(): StopIteration')    
      
main()
```

When ran, this example will produce the following output, showing which values arrive in the generator and which are returned by the generator:

```
main(): first
f(): 1
main(): second
f(): 2
main(): StopIteration
```

Wrapping the generator `f()` by changing the statement `gen = f()` to `gen = Intercept(f())`, produces the following output, showing that the first yielded value has been replaced:

```
Intercepted value: first
main(): intercepted
f(): 1
main(): second
f(): 2
```

As all other calls to any of the generator API are forwarded directly to the wrapped generator, it should behave equivalently to the wrapped generator itself.

Comment: "The specification contains a (surprisingly complex) piece of sample code"—yes, that's precisely why I didn't want to re-implement `yield from` :) I've realised that, as you say, there is currently no solution using `yield from`. And I think this approach is the best we can achieve without (re-)writing too much code. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the question, I think this works?  Meaning, I ran this script and it did what I expected, which was to print all but the first line of the input file.  But as long as the generator passed as the argument to the `skip_first` function can be iterator over, it should work.

```
def skip_first(thing):
    _first = True
    for _result in thing:
        if _first:
        _   first = False
            continue
        yield _result

inp = open("/var/tmp/test.txt")

for line in skip_first(inp):
    print(line, end="")
```

Comment: This completely ignores `.send`, `.throw`, `.close`... [Python generators are more than a simple iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-iterator-methods). (And the intent is to intercept and transform the first yielded value, not to skip it entirely, but this is secondary.)

Comment: I use class based generators, so trying to squeeze it into a function was a challenge. :)